# Cant Login to Protonmail with PhantomJS

Tags: authentication, click, phantomjs

I'm trying to enter in protonmail using PhantonJS. I enter my login and password and I want to press the Login button. Do not press. As I tried to press. So.

```
page.evaluate(function(ps,p){
    var eps=ps;
    var ep=p;
    document.getElementById("username").value = eps;
    document.getElementById("password").value = ep;
    var lbx1x1x1a = document.getElementById("login_btn");
    var lbx1x1x1e = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
    lbx1x1x1e.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
    lbx1x1x1a.dispatchEvent(lbx1x1x1e);
},ps,p);
```

Does not work, nothing happens

So:

```
 var point = page.evaluate(function () {
    var element = document.getElementById('login_btn');
    var rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
         return {
                 x: rect.left + Math.floor(rect.width / 2),
                y: rect.top + Math.floor(rect.height / 2)
        };
});
point.x=Math.floor(point.x);
point.y=Math.floor(point.y); 
console.log(point.x+" "+point.y);
page.sendEvent('click', point.x, point.y);
```

Does not work, nothing happens

```
page.evaluate(function(ps,p){
    var eps=ps;
    var ep=p;
    document.getElementById("username").value = eps;
   document.getElementById("password").value = ep;
    document.getElementById("pm_login").submit();

},ps,p);
```

Does not work, but the fields of the logs and password are cleaned out

```
page.evaluate(function(ps,p){
    var eps=ps;
    var ep=p;
    document.getElementById("username").value = eps;
    document.getElementById("password").focus();
},ps,p);

page.sendEvent('keypress', "123\r"); 
page.sendEvent('keypress', page.event.key.A, null, null, 0x02000000 | 0x08000000);
```

Does not work, nothing happens

```
page.evaluate(function(ps,p){
    var eps=ps;
    var ep=p;
    document.getElementById("username").value = eps;
    document.getElementById("password").value = ep;
    document.getElementById("login_btn").focus();
},ps,p);

page.sendEvent('keypress', "\r"); 
page.sendEvent('keypress', page.event.key.A, null, null, 0x02000000 | 0x08000000);
```

Does not work, nothing happens. 
No more ideas, and you?
Thank you.

Phantomjs 2.1.1

Hello! Thanks for Vaviloff).
I paste that code, for err detect.

```
page.evaluate(function(ps,p){
    var eps=ps;
    var ep=p;
    document.getElementById("username").value = eps;
    document.getElementById("password").value = ep;
    document.getElementById("login_btn").click();
    var lbx1x1x1a = document.getElementById("login_btn");
    var lbx1x1x1e = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
    lbx1x1x1e.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
    lbx1x1x1a.dispatchEvent(lbx1x1x1e);
},ps,p);

    page.onResourceError = function(resourceError) {
        console.log('Unable to load resource (#' + resourceError.id + 'URL:' + resourceError.url + ')');
        console.log('Error code: ' + resourceError.errorCode + '. Description: ' + resourceError.errorString);
    };

    page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg, lineNum, sourceId) {
        console.log('CONSOLE: ' + msg + ' (from line #' + lineNum + ' in "' + sourceId + '")');
    };

    page.onError = function(msg, trace) {
        var msgStack = ['ERROR: ' + msg];
        if (trace && trace.length) {
            msgStack.push('TRACE:');
            trace.forEach(function(t) {
                msgStack.push(' -> ' + t.file + ': ' + t.line + (t.function ? ' (in function "' + t.function +'")' : ''));
            });
        }
        console.error(msgStack.join('\n'));
    };
```

No error.
When I run a phantomjs I get the following message in the console, but that's before I try to click on the login.

```
TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'navLang.includes("-")')
https://protonmail.com/js/site.js?rel=b38297243e:6
https://protonmail.com/js/site.js?rel=b38297243e:2 in j
https://protonmail.com/js/site.js?rel=b38297243e:2 in fireWith
https://protonmail.com/js/site.js?rel=b38297243e:2 in ready
https://protonmail.com/js/site.js?rel=b38297243e:1 in J
```

At the same time on the same page I can click on other elements and it will work. The following code works as it should.

```
page.evaluate(function(ps,p){
    var eps=ps;
    var ep=p;
    document.getElementById("username").value = eps;
    document.getElementById("password").value = ep;
    var lbx1x1x1a =document.getElementsByClassName ("loginForm-btn-help")[0];
    var lbx1x1x1e = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
    lbx1x1x1e.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
    lbx1x1x1a.dispatchEvent(lbx1x1x1e);

},ps,p);
```

or

```
page.evaluate(function(ps,p){
    var eps=ps;
    var ep=p;
    document.getElementById("username").value = eps;
    document.getElementById("password").value = ep;
    var lbx1x1x1a =document.getElementsByClassName ("loginForm-actions-main pm_button primary pull-right loginForm-btn-submit")[0];
    var lbx1x1x1e = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
    lbx1x1x1e.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
    lbx1x1x1a.dispatchEvent(lbx1x1x1e);
},ps,p);
```

[ScreenShot - signup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c71S6.png)

Other elements are clickable, no login.
I can not press it. 
where is the catch?
Thanks.

So does not work either:

```
page.includeJs('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js');
    setTimeout(InterLoginData, 90000);


function InterLoginData(){
console.log ("Phantomjs.InterLoginData and Login.");
page.evaluate(function(ps,p){
    var eps=ps;
    var ep=p;
    document.getElementById("username").value = eps;
   document.getElementById("password").value = ep;
    //document.getElementById("password").focus();

    document.getElementById("login_btn").click();
    document.getElementById("login_btn").submit();

    $("login_btn").click();
    $("#login_btn").click();

    $("login_btn").submit();
    $("#login_btn").submit();


},ps,p);
```

Frome Google chrome console That:

```
document.getElementById("login_btn").click();
```

and that code:

```
var lbx1x1x1a = document.getElementById("login_btn");
var lbx1x1x1e = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
lbx1x1x1e.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
lbx1x1x1a.dispatchEvent(lbx1x1x1e);
```

works correctly. Throw ideas please. Thanks.

Comment: Try checking for errors with page.onError callback.are there any?

Comment: Hello! Vaviloff thanks)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out, the button was pressed. But.
It turned out that after the code:

```
page.evaluate(function(ps,p){
   var eps=ps;
   var ep=p;
   document.getElementById("username").value = eps;
   document.getElementById("password").value = ep;
},ps,p);
```

The page considered that the login and password fields are not filled. And the page gave a message asking to fill in the fields. I did not see the site in the screenshots because it appeared for a short time and at the time of the screen capture it was already disappearing. I was able to see this by running the code in SlimerJS (Thank you). The following code works as it should, the button to enter is pressed and I went into my mail.)
Thanks all.

```
//*************
var ps="PUT_LOGIN_HERE"
var p="PUT_PASSWORD_HERE"
//*************

page.evaluate(function(){
    document.getElementById("username").focus();
});
page.sendEvent('keypress', ps);


page.evaluate(function(){
    document.getElementById("password").focus();
});
page.sendEvent('keypress', p);
page.sendEvent('keypress', "\n");//Enter
```